# Error while building the code on workspace of ros2 crystal on ubentu 18.04

Tags: ros2

am trying to build ros2 crystal ws on ubentu 18 but i got this:

cmd
~/ros2_crystal$ vcs import src < ros2.repos
error:
usage: vcs import [-h] [–input FILE_OR_URL] [–force] [–shallow]
[–recursive] [–retry N] [–skip-existing] [–debug] [-w N]
[–repos]
[path]
vcs import: error: argument path: Path ‘src’ does not exist.